# Javascript Aptana assist extend

Tags: javascript, aptana

#### Code:

```
var a={
    value:5,
    test:function()
    {
        this.value=4;
    }
}



var b=someFunction(
{
    value:5,
    test:function()
    {
        this.value=4;
    }
});
```

As you see they are look the same, diffrence is only that in first case we define object, in second, we pass this object into function.

The problem is that in first case I see code assist when I type "this.v" (as a this.value) , but cant see that in second case. I tried creating an object, then use as a argument for this function - this works, but unfortunately automatic documentation script need code to be in the second version. My question is - Can I force Aptana somehow to use object passed into functions the same way as it do like in declared object? I figured out that it does code assist on "= {}" declaration. I would like to extend this to any "{}" occurence. Anyone have idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only by extending Aptana Java files. No other way - maybe future Aptana will support this by default...